# How to retrieve the index value in serial wise in given Object

Tags: javascript, angular

In given object there are different set of questions ex. (label, question text), each object set has "QuestionTypeId".
If QuestionTypeId is "18" then question is "label" and the label shouldn't have the number(index value). Each label may have one or more questionText with index value.

Here i just need to display the index value to the questionText whose QuestionTypeId is different and not "18". To only those questionText number or index value need to be added serial wise, below is the image which is shown in the correct format.

[[image]]

The result shown in the image is i m trying to get

Below is the code which i have tried to get the result:

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  globalJsonData = {
    "parent": {
      "child": [{
          "QuestionId": 349,
          "QuestionText": "This is Label One",
          "QuestionTypeId": 18,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 340,
          "QuestionText": "This is Question Text One",
          "QuestionTypeId": 17,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 350,
          "QuestionText": "This is Label Two",
          "QuestionTypeId": 18,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 352,
          "QuestionText": "This is Question Text Two",
          "QuestionTypeId": 17,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 354,
          "QuestionText": "This is Question Text Three",
          "QuestionTypeId": 6,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 350,
          "QuestionText": "This is Label Three",
          "QuestionTypeId": 18,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 353,
          "QuestionText": "This is Question Text Four",
          "QuestionTypeId": 17,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        },
        {
          "QuestionId": 355,
          "QuestionText": "This is Question Text Five",
          "QuestionTypeId": 8,
          "QuestionSetCode": 166378
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  result;
  questionList = []
  ngOnInit() {
    this.callGenerateConfig()
  }
  callGenerateConfig() {
    let data = [];
    data = this.globalJsonData.parent.child;
    data.forEach((question, index) => {
      let prevHasLabel = question.QuestionTypeId == 18 ? true : false;
      this.result = ( !prevHasLabel? index == 0 ? 1 : index : index - 1 );
      question['result'] = this.result;
      this.questionList.push(question);
    })
  }
}
```

```html
<ul *ngFor="let data of questionList; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="data.QuestionTypeId == 18; else elseBlock">
    <li [ngStyle]="{
    'font-size': '20px',
    'font-weight': 'bold'}">{{data.QuestionText}}</li>
  </div>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <li [ngStyle]="{'background-color': 'lime',
    'font-size': '20px',
    'font-weight': 'bold'}">{{data.result}} === {{data.QuestionText}}</li>
    .</ng-template>
</ul>
```

Using the above solution i have got this result:

[image]

Please help me to get the solution, or index value in serial wise for each question text skipping the label.

Also this the link for stackblizt here is the code which i tried:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xebvm4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should loop over `li` not on `ul`. Also it can be done in simpler way.

This is how you should do it :

in `component.ts` file , process your data as follows :

```
callGenerateConfig() {
    let data = [];
    data = this.globalJsonData.parent.child;
    let position = 1;

    data.forEach((item, index) => {
      let isLabel = item.QuestionTypeId === 18;
      console.log(isLabel);
      let obj = {
        label: isLabel,
        data: item,
        location: position
      }
      if (!isLabel) {
        position++;
      }
      this.questionList.push(obj);
    })
  }
```

in `component.html` do below :

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let data of questionList">
      <span *ngIf="data.label===false"> {{data.location}}</span>
      <span> {{data.data.QuestionText}}</span>
   </li>  
</ul>
```

Here is the working example : [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rcwls6)